# Determining implementation of Python at runtime?

Tags: python

I'm writing a piece of code that returns profiling information and it would be helpful to be able to dynamically return the implementation of Python in use.

Is there a Pythonic way to determine which implementation (e.g. Jython, PyPy) of Python my code is executing on at runtime?  I know that I am able to get version information from `sys.version`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, May  1 2015, 19:14:18) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49)]'
```

but I'm not sure where to look in the `sys` module to get the implementation that the code is running.

Comment: @Jasper that question deals with returning the *version* of Python, not the implementation.

Comment: You failed to define "implementation" although you did with clarity in your own answer.

Comment: @msw I'm not sure I agree.  The official wiki uses the same language: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations In any case, apologies if there was vagueness in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `python_implementation` from the `platform` module in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation) or [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation).  This returns a string that identifies the Python implementation.

e.g.

`return_implementation.py`

```
import platform
print(platform.python_implementation())
```

and iterating through some responses on the command line:

```
$ for i in python python3 pypy pypy3; do echo -n "implementation $i: "; $i return_implementation.py; done
implementation python: CPython
implementation python3: CPython
implementation pypy: PyPy
implementation pypy3: PyPy
```

Note as of this answer's date, the possible responses are 'CPython', 'IronPython', 'Jython', 'PyPy', meaning that it's possible that your implementation will not be returned by this `python_implementation` function if it does not identity to the `sys` module as one of these types.

[`python_implementation` is calling `sys.version`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/platform.py#l1207) under the hood and attempting to match the response to a regex pattern -- if there's no conditional match, there's no matching string response.